# "DESCRIBE" is giving syntax error in mysql

Tags: mysql, syntax, describe

**CODE:**
CREATE TABLE students (
id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
name VARCHAR(20),
major VARCHAR(20)
);
DESCRIBE students;
**RESULT:**
Error: near line 6: near "DESCRIBE": syntax error

Answer (score 1):

Most interfaces to MySQL query API only allow one query at a time. Multi-query is optional, but not enabled by default. You didn't describe what language or interface you're using, but odds are that multi-query is not enabled.

Easy workaround: Run one query per API call. Don't try to run multiple queries separated by semicolons.

There is no good reason to use multi-query anyway.